# Navigate to another scene using NavigatiorIOS in React-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm just a beginner when it comes to React-Native and I am a bit unsure on how to correctly use the **NavigatorIOS**. 
So here's the thing, I have a file called `index.ios.js` that includes another file called `walkthroughPage.js`. `walkthroughPage` is just a walkthrough screen.

**index.ios.js**

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native')
var walkthroughPage = require('./components/pages/walkthroughPage')

var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  NavigatorIOS,
} = React;

var blackcab = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
        style={styles.wrapper}
        initialRoute={{
          component: walkthroughPage,
          title: 'Välkommen',
        }}
      />
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    flex: 1,
  },
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('blackcab', () => blackcab);
```

In this screen I can see a NavigationBar so I'm guessing it kinda works, here to the problem.

In `walkthroughPage.js` I have a button handler which tells an event to be fired.

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native')
var Button = require('react-native-button')
var Swiper = require('react-native-swiper')
var authenticationPage = require('./components/pages/authenticationPage')

var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
} = React;

var walkthroughPage = React.createClass({

  _getStartedButtonPress: function() {
    this.props.navigator.push(authenticationPage);
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <Swiper style={styles.wrapper} showsButtons={false}>
        <View style={styles.slide1}>
          <Image
            style={styles.icon}
            source={require('image!F_icon.svg')}
          />
          <Text style={styles.text}>Anslut med Facebook</Text>
          <Text style={styles.paragraph}>Använd Facebook för att snabbt kunnna komma igång med Black Cab</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.slide2}>
          <Image
            style={styles.icon}
            source={require('image!map')}
          />
          <Text style={styles.text}>Hitta chaufförer i närheten</Text>
          <Text style={styles.paragraph}>Aktivera platstjänster på din telefon så vi kan använda din GPS, då slipper du bokstavera på fyllan</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.slide3}>
          <Image
            style={styles.money}
            source={require('image!coin')}
          />
          <Text style={styles.text}>Spara pengar</Text>
          <Text style={styles.paragraph}>Alla vet att svarttaxi är billigt, du är medveten om det va?</Text>
          <Button style={styles.skip} onPress={this._getStartedButtonPress}>
            Kom igång
          </Button>
        </View>
      </Swiper>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
  },
  slide1: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
  slide2: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
  slide3: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
  text: {
    color: '#2A2B30',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
  paragraph: {
    color: '#b7b7b7',
    marginTop: 25,
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: 'center',
    width: 340,
    lineHeight: 25,
  },
  skip: {
    color: '#567BEC',
    marginTop: 100,
  },
  icon: {
    marginTop: -150,
    marginBottom: 30,
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
  },
  money: {
    marginTop: -100,
    marginBottom: 30,
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
  },
})

module.exports = walkthroughPage;
```

**authenticationPage.js**

```
 'use strict';

var React = require('react-native')

var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} = React;

var authenticationPage = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.ios.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
          Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

module.exports = authenticationPage;
```

How do I tell `_getStartedButtonPress` to push to the correct view, how do I include the view within the `_getStartedButtonPress` function?

I get this error `Requiring unknown module ”./components/pages/authenticationPage”.`

I have restarted the packager, cleaned the Xcode-project and rebuild & run. No luck, how come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the unknown module issue: the path to the file is relative.  So if the walkthroughPage.js is in components/pages, the relative path to include authentication page would need to be `require('./authenticationPage')`.

Richard Kho's response on how to use the navigator is correct.  You can't pass it just a component - you need to pass it an object that represents a route (of which "component" is one property).

Comment: The string of code you wrote there actually got if working, so not quite sure how I will hand out the points..

Comment: You can give them to Richard Kho

Answer (score 2):

First things first: Make sure the path to `authenticationPage` is accurate. It looks like your path isn't correct.

Second, here's how you push the next route:

```
this.props.navigator.push({
  title: 'Web',
  component: Web,
  passProps: {url: this.state.productLink}
})
```

- `title` is the name you'd like on the navigation bar
- `component` is
  the actual component you're passing
- `passProps` is where you pass,
  well, any props to that component

Comment: The path to my `authenticationPage` is correct, it's correctly pointed to the component but I'm still getting `Requiring unknown module`..

Comment: Just to confirm -- is this an error that occurs when the button on `walkthroughPage` is pressed or when `walkthroughPage` attempts to be mounted?

Comment: As soon as I fire up the app. http://imgh.us/iOS_Simulator_Screen_Shot_16_jul_2015_00.48.08.png

Comment: If you remove all references to `authenticationPage` in `walkthroughPage`, does the issue persist? Things I would try right now on top of that: REALLY make sure your path and your files are spelled correctly; clean and rebuild your app in Xcode (command + option + shift + k); append `.js` to the end of that path if it's a direct file and not a folder

Comment: When removing references the app loads, added the `.js` at the end and also double checked the paths, now I have cleaned the Xcode project and also rebuilt it. Still the same error :/

Comment: Hi, please update your version of React Native and make any necessary fixes. If that doesn't solve your issue, I would suggest that you create a new question.